# Cannot find component with identifier

Tags: jsf

I want to update the `resultMediaTable` in the p:commandButton I added `update=":mediaSelectForm:resultMediaTable"` but I got error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Cannot find component with identifier ":mediaSelectForm:resultMediaTable" referenced from "mainForm:mediaSearchForm:searchButton".
```

```
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <p:dialog id="mediaSelectDialog" header="#{ui['action.search']} #{ui['media.title1']}" widgetVar="mediaDialog" resizable="false" modal="true"
        styleClass="searchDialog">
        <h:form id="mediaSearchForm">
            <p:inputText id="searchInput" value="#{mediaAssigner.mediaSearchQuery}" />
            <p:watermark for="searchInput" value="#{ui['shared.name']}" />
            <p:commandButton id="searchButton" value="#{ui['action.search']}" actionListener="#{mediaAssigner.searchMediaVideos}"
                update=":mediaSelectForm:resultMediaTable" icon="ui-icon-search" process="@parent" />
        </h:form>
        <h:form id="mediaSelectForm">
            <p:dataTable id="resultMediaTable" var="media" value="#{mediaAssigner.resultMedia}" paginator="true" rows="10"
                selection="#{liveStreamController.liveStream.media}" rowKey="#{media.id}" paginatorPosition="bottom" selectionMode="single">
                <p:column headerText="#{ui['shared.id']}" style="width: 20%">
               #{media.id}
            </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="#{ui['shared.name']}">
               #{media.name}
            </p:column>
                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <p:commandButton value="#{ui['liveStream.assignMedia']}" update=":mainForm:mediaText :mainForm:runtime :mainForm:addMedia"
                        oncomplete="mediaDialog.hide()" process="resultMediaTable" actionListener="#{mediaAssigner.onMediaAssigned(liveStreamController.liveStream)}" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
</ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by add `update=":mainForm:mediaSelectForm:resultMediaTable"`